# How to create a 'most popular content' view?

Tags: views, 8, nodes

I'd like to get a view block listing the most viewed articles.

What are the options to do that with drupal 8?

**Note**: I have activated the core module named 'statistics' and configured 'Increment a counter each time content is viewed.' But I cannot select that field for sorting in Views.

Comment: I have activated the core module named 'statistics' and configure 'Increment a counter each time content is viewed. ' but i cannot select that field for sorting in views

Answer (score 3):

After activating the "Statistics" core module and checking the "Count content views" option in /admin/config/system/statistics, as you mention, you can select "Total views" as sort criteria (see screenshot).

[image]

Comment: thanks, have u tried it ? i display the total views on my view ,my counter stay to 0, whatever clicks i make to display the node!?

Comment: @Matoeil, it is indeed necessary to check the "Count content views" option, I have just edited my answer. I have just tried it on a "vanilla" local Drupal 8 install and it is working: The counter is being incremented every time I click on a node and the view is displaying it.

Comment: weird it does not work in my view

Comment: Be careful with the statistics module, it can be a performance hog.

Drupal.org recommends disabling it to improve performance:
https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/managing-site-performance-and-scalability/optimizing-drupal-to-load-faster-server-mysql

It fires db_queries for every node, logged in or logged out.

it is constantly firing db queries for every user on every page. logged in and out.  And for every teaser on a landing page.  If you have twenty or thirty on the landing page, that's a lot of queries.